# R set plot background based on date

Tags: r, date, plot

I have a chart of financial activity and a couple running sums.[image]  Things are getting a little busy and I'm having trouble distinguishing fiscal (ends June 30th) vs calendar year.  Is there a way to set the background to different colors based on date?

In other words could I set background to lite green where 2009-06-30 < date < 2010-07-01?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply a piece of both suggestions by @G-Grothendieck and @vincent - use `rect` within `zoo` package. `zoo` is excellent for any visualization of time series.

```
library(zoo)
#random data combined with time series that starts in 2009-01
v <- zooreg(rnorm(37), start = as.yearmon("2009-1"), freq=12)
plot(v, type = "n",xlab="",xaxt="n")
#this will catch some min and max values for y-axis points in rect
u <- par("usr")
#plot green rect - notice that x-coordinates are defined by date points
rect(as.yearmon("2009-6-30"), u[3], as.yearmon("2010-7-1"), u[4], 
        border = 0, col = "lightgreen")
lines(v)
axis(1, floor(time(v)))
#customized x-axis labels based on dates values
axis(1,at=c(2009.4, 2010.5),padj=-2,lty=0,labels=c("start","end"),cex.axis=0.8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Check out `xblocks.zoo` in the zoo  package. e.g., `example(xblocks.zoo)`

Answer (score 2):

You can plot grey rectangles, with `rect`, before plotting the curves.
You will also need the dimensions of the plotting area: they are in `par("usr")`.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("A")
plot( index(A), coredata(Ad(A)), type="n" )
# This example uses calendar years: adapt as needed
dates <- c( 
  ISOdate( year(min(index(A))),     1, 1 ),
  ISOdate( year(max(index(A))) + 1, 1, 1 )
)
dates <- as.Date(dates)
dates <- seq.Date(dates[1], dates[2], by="2 year")
rect( 
  dates, 
  par("usr")[3], 
  as.Date( ISOdate( year(dates) + 1, 1, 1 ) ),
  par("usr")[4], 
  col="grey",
  border=NA
)
lines(index(A), coredata(Ad(A)), lwd=3)
```